# How to turn rows into columns in an R dataframe?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-conversion

I want all my rows to be converted to their own columns so everything will be in one row in the end. This is how my dataframe looks now:

```
   track                    time UTM_WGS84.Longitude UTM_WGS84.Latitude
1       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.711            5.481687           51.43635
2       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.717            5.481689           51.43635
3       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.723            5.481689           51.43635
4       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.730            5.481690           51.43635
5       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.763            5.481691           51.43635
6       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.804            5.481691           51.43635
7       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.840            5.481692           51.43635
8       2 2015-10-14 23:59:55.882            5.481692           51.43635
9       2 2015-10-14 23:59:56.031            5.481693           51.43635
10      2 2015-10-14 23:59:56.041            5.481693           51.43635
11      2 2015-10-14 23:59:56.047            5.481693           51.43635
12      2 2015-10-14 23:59:56.053            5.481694           51.43635
13      3 2015-10-14 23:59:56.081            5.481695           51.43635
14      3 2015-10-14 23:59:56.121            5.481695           51.43635
15      3 2015-10-14 23:59:56.165            5.481695           51.43635
```

I'm not sure if this is doable but this is what I want the columns to look like:

```
time1.1 - UTM_WGS84.Longitude1.1 - UTM_WGS84.Latitude1.1 -  time1.2 - UTM_WGS84.Longitude1.2 - UTM_WGS84.Latitude1.2 - time2.1 -  UTM_WGS84.Longitude2.1 - UTM_WGS84.Latitude2.1
```

Where the first number is the track and the second number is the row of that track.
I know it's a weird request but I'm trying to find a way to give all this data to a machine learning method to recognize walking patterns.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Please provide the data in an easy-to-paste form and possibly the way the expected result is suppose to look like.

Comment: You have a strange machine learning method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this demo:

```
> df <- data.frame(track = c(2,1,5), A = c(1,2,3), B = c(100, 200, 300))
> df
  track A   B
1     2 1 100
2     1 2 200
3     5 3 300
```

As you wish, one row in the end, meaning combine all rows to one list ? So:

```
> ls <- unlist(as.list(t(df)))
> ls
[1]   2   1 100   1   2 200   5   3 300
```

But how to deal with column names ? A dumb approach may work out:

```
> row.num <- row.names(df)
> row.num
[1] "1" "2" "3"
> column.name <- colnames(df)
> column.name
[1] "track" "A"     "B"    
> track <- as.character(df$track)
> track
[1] "2" "1" "5"
```

Then get new column names:

```
> new.column.names <- c()
> for(i in 1:length(track)) {
     for(k in 1:length(column.name)) {
         str <- paste(column.name[k], track[i], sep = "")
         str <- paste(str, row.num[i], sep = ".")
         new.column.names <- c(new.column.names, str)
         }
     }
> new.column.names
[1] "track2.1" "A2.1"     "B2.1"     "track1.2" "A1.2"     "B1.2"     "track5.3"
[8] "A5.3"     "B5.3"
```

At last, assign `ls` and `new.column.names` to your new data frame:

```
> new.df <- t(data.frame(ls))
> colnames(new.df) <- new.column.names
> rownames(new.df) <- 1
```

> Result:

```
> new.df
  track2.1 A2.1 B2.1 track1.2 A1.2 B1.2 track5.3 A5.3 B5.3
1        2    1  100        1    2  200        5    3  300
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you want:

```
df=matrix(1:12,ncol=3)
df
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    5    9
#[2,]    2    6   10
#[3,]    3    7   11
#[4,]    4    8   12
c(t(df))
# [1]  1  5  9  2  6 10  3  7 11  4  8 12
```

As data frame

```
data.frame(t(c(t(df))))
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12
#1  1  5  9  2  6 10  3  7 11   4   8  12
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a good start but this is a list and what I want is a dataframe. Is it possible for all these numbers to have their own column?